# Can I use a constructor or an object as an other class method's argument default value?

Tags: c++, function, object, constructor, default-value

I have tried to use a constructor as a default value in a method declaration, like this:

A.hpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
class B;
Class A {
friend class B;
    public:
    A();
    ~A();
    const A& operator = (const A& rhs) {
        // assignment operations
        return *this;
    }
    int do_something (B* pB);
};
```

B.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
class B {
    public:
    B(const A a = A());
    ~B();
};
```

My gcc 4.8 C++11 compiler is not happy with the line `B(const A a = A());`:

> error: 'A' does not name a type error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'A' with no type [-fpermissive]

I need a default value for a, and I don't want to use a pointer like in `B(A *a = NULL, int z = 0);`.

I have also tried to declare a static element and use this object as the default value:

A.hpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
class B;
class A {
    // ...
};
```

B.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
A a0;
class B {
    public:
    B(const A a = a0);
    ~B();
};
```

I get exactly the same errors.

How can I achieve that please ?

EDIT: make the code closer to the real code.

Comment: Is this your real code? There are no semicolons after class definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it when writing the example. The original code is right. So, the original question remains the same.

Comment: There's not enough information as it is. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be useful here.

Comment: Your `A` constructor is `private`. Other than that, the code you have posted has no error. http://ideone.com/c5esGG

Comment: This won't work in `A.cpp` as when `B.hpp` is processed, `A` is not defined yet. `A` must be fully defined at the point you want to write `B(A a = A())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the origin of the problem, it was due to a bad use of `#include`.

Removing the line `#include "B.hpp"` in A.hpp solves the problem. The A header only needs a forward declaration of class B, since it uses only a pointer to this class. I conclude I had a circular header reference. I thought that using `friend` requires to include the header of the class. Note: class B needs to access actually some private members of class A.

Sorry for my bad initial post, it was impossible to diagnose anything from it since it was not close enough from the real one (coorected). I will stick to SSCCE next time. Thanks everyone. As the buddy concludes [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/132951/trying-to-create-a-class), "That was really stupid". Then I found detailed explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413403/why-must-we-forward-declare-a-class-and-include-the-corresponding-header-file-in) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).

Answer (score 4):

You have to add semicolons after the closing brace of your classes.

```
class A        class A
{              {

} /* bad */    }; /* good */
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the static variable declaration `a0` to AFTER the definition of class A, like so:

```
class A
{
    // class definition
};

A a0;

class B
{
    B (const A a = a0);
};
```

Comment: The class declarations are in headers, so it is correct.

Comment: I don't understand what correct means. When the compiler reads the line `A a0`, if the identifier `A` is not declared to be a class by then, the compiler will issue an error.

Comment: The problem is not that it's unclear. It's what I believe is causing the error. Change it in your code, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

[Your code works just fine, mate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6910ef9fa65da974)!